# How to sort by likes or views Flask?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a problem sorting **Authors** by `Author.likes` or `Author.views` .

Lets me first show you my codes snippets :

**views.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import func
@app.route('/authors/')
def authors():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    pagination = Author.query.order_by(func.count(Author.likes)).paginate(page, per_page=app.config['AUTHORS_PER_PAGE'], error_out=False)
```

Here am using the func.count() function to sort the authors ordered by `likes`.

The problem is am getting just the most liked author , in fact i have 12 of them in the database each one has his likes, so i need to sort them all by likes from the highest one to the lowest .

I tried a different ways but without avail , please any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `func.count` and just order by `Author.likes`, it's already a count.  `func.count` is for counting groups of things.  Currently, you're grouping everything into one group and so you only get one item back.